# How to save file in JAR?

Tags: java, jar

I know how to get resource, eg. image or text file. But how do I save file in JAR? Is there some way to do it with using getClass() like I do while getting resources? If not, what is the beginning of path?

Comment: I don't think it is possible...check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to add a file to a JAR, see the documentation at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

The command is `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`.  If you are looking to do this programmatically, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarEntry.html for the `JarEntry` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a way to do this using jar command.You can check [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to put your resources into JAR files at the time when your JAR (or program) is packaged.

For example if you are using Maven to build your program, simply put all required files to src/main/resources directory (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).